# Rails application not responding on DigitalOcean with Unicorn/nginx combination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm hosting an API for a mobile app developed in Rails 4 on DigitalOcean using the One-Click Ubuntu 12.10 Installation droplet. Therefore nginx and Unicorn are preconfigured and running. When I try to open a file from Rails public folder on my web browser, it works.

But when I try to use any of the other paths defined in the `routes.rb` file I don't get any answer. My requests are loading until they time out. This changes when I type `rails s -e production` on the server – **then everything works as expected**. Therefore it must be a problem with nginx or something. What am I missing?

Here's my nginx `sites-enabled/default` file content (I don't know if that's the thing to look for, but maybe):

```
server {
    listen   80;
    root /home/rails/public;
    server_name _;
    index index.htm index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    }

    #location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|mid$
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rt$
            try_files $uri @app;
     }

     location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
     }

}
```

**UPDATE:** Here is my `nginx.conf` file in case this helps:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/comma-separated-values;
    upstream app_server { server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0; }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** And here my `unicorn.conf` file:

```
listen "127.0.0.1:8080"
worker_processes 2
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails"
pid "/home/unicorn/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and running `bundle install` on the root of my app (on digitalocean droplet) resolved my issue. I think I have to build that into my capistrano script

Comment: I've tried (again) but unfortunately this did not solve my problem. :(